# compile a .c file with dependencies

Tags: c, makefile

I 'inherited' a bunch of files from my professor and she asked me to see if I can make sense of the whole project. Its a mish-mash of a bunch of files ( `python, c, java`) that are to be run one after the other on a particular data set. From what I have seen the code is very poorly written and the README is a joke.

The first step involves running a python script with the dataset and 2 more arguments. The last line of this file is

```
os.system("./blar " + str(raw_datafile) + " " + str(combos) + " " + str(mine1) + " " + str(mine2))
```

which translates to -

```
./blar RareDiseaseDataSet.xlsx 57 1 84
```

I know `os.system` executes a command in a subshell. however when the above command is executed the result is `./blar: No such file or directory`. The folder has a file named `blar.c` . My `c` knowledge is very basic , in order to generate an executable i tried `make blar.c` , `gcc blar.c -o blar` but to no avail. How do I get this to run?

**EDIT**
Tried these commands -

```
$ make blar.c
make: Nothing to be done for `blar.c'.

$ gcc blar.c -o blar
/tmp/ccblMR3s.o: In function `nonsingles':
blar.c:(.text+0x359): undefined reference to `checknull'
blar.c:(.text+0x3e3): undefined reference to `checknull'
blar.c:(.text+0x759): undefined reference to `next_comb'
/tmp/ccblMR3s.o: In function `main':
blar.c:(.text+0xa20): undefined reference to `readfile'
blar.c:(.text+0xa2d): undefined reference to `checknull'
blar.c:(.text+0xb44): undefined reference to `destroy_file_array'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**TL;DR**
How to create an executable from a `.c` file.

P.S. - Running this on a school server, which is prehistoric and uses python 2.4.x

Comment: C needs to be compiled before it can be executed, here: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html may be a good place to start.

Comment: You can use ctypes to call compiled C libraries.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen` is better than `os.system`

Comment: im using `python 2.4`, subprocess is not available

Comment: `make blar.c` is pointless: It asks make if it knows a rule to create `blar.c`; but you have it already. Try `make blar`.

Comment: The gcc error shows that my hunch (in my answer) was right: `blar.c` needs to be compiled together with other `.c` files (or possibly libraries, but I doubt it), which provide `checknull`, `next_comb`, etc. You could grep for them and add them one at a time, but first figure out if the makefile can do it: Try `make blar`, and plain `make`.

Comment: Another thought: Given the trouble you're having with this basic step, it's possible that the README is not as bad as you claim: Maybe it'll make sense to someone with a bit more experience. If there's someone like that around, ask them to sit with you and look at the project. It might be trivial once they can see the whole thing. Oh and python knowledge is not needed, that part seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with `gcc blar.c -o blar`. Presumably it failed, so you have to figure out why (examine the error message) and fix that. If there's a `Makefile` in the directory, it'll contain recipes for building everything (if you're lucky).

PS. Looks like your `blar` program has to be able to read an Excel spreadsheet; almost certainly it relies on additional source files or libraries, so you'll need to compile and/or link additional files in the command that builds `blar`. I really hope you've got a `Makefile`.

Comment: The command to execute the makefile is just `make` executed from the same dir as the makefile.

Comment: Indeed. Do try typing `make`, maybe you'll luck out and everything will Just Work.